# How do I update fields for multiple elements in an array with different values in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have data of the form:

```
{
   '_id': asdf123b51234
   'field2': 0
   'array': [
           0: {
                   'unique_array_elem_id': id
                   'nested_field': {
                                  'new_field_i_want_to_add': value
                                 }
                   }
           ...
           ]
}
```

I have been trying to update like this:

```
for doc in update_dict:
   collection.find_one_and_update(
      {'_id':doc['_id']},
      {'$set': {
         'array.$[elem].nested_field.new_field_i_want_to_add':doc['new_field_value']
         }
      },
      array_filters=[{'elem.unique_array_elem_id':doc['unique_array_elem_id']}]
```

But it is painfully slow. Updating all of my data will take several days running continuously. Is there a way to update this nested field for all array elements for a given document at once?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps a `bulk_write` with [`UpdateOne`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/operations.html?highlight=UpdateOne#pymongo.operations.UpdateOne) operations will have higher performance.

Comment: If you have any indexes on `"array.nested_field.new_field_i_want_to_add"`, you may want to drop them before the `bulk_write` so the server won't spend time updating them.  After the `bulk_write` you can re-create the indexes.

Comment: Similar comments for `validation`.  If you don't want the server to spend time validating, don't use it.